# Require tree in asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pipeline, assets

I have a folder in my asset pipeline called typefaces. It works without any additions to `application.rb`.

In the directory I have different typeface types, like .eof, .ttf, etc in folders, like this

```
Assets
    Typefaces
        Eof
           ...files
        Ttf
           ...files
```

Unless the typefaces are in Assets/typefaces they don't become part of asset pipeline. Asset pipeline doesn't go into the subdirectories.

How would I have asset pipeline look beyond assets/typefaces into assets/typefaces/eof, assets/typefaces/ttf etc?

Comment: how are you currently requiring the typefaces?

Comment: They're in a typefaces directory but not within subfolders, like above, I'd like them in subfolders... (Eof, ttf, etc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, try putting:

`//= require_tree ../Typefaces`

See more: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, it looks like application.js may just add javascripts...

"The directives that work in the JavaScript files also work in stylesheets (though obviously including stylesheets rather than JavaScript files). The require_tree directive in a CSS manifest works the same way as the JavaScript one, requiring all stylesheets from the current directory."

Comment: You probably will need to add them to your `config/environments/production.rb` file. Look for the following line:

`# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )`

Comment: I don't think it can work, I had to move them to a /typefaces directory but they couldn't be like /typefaces/mono/

Answer (score 8):

In application.css

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./folder_name/

*/
```

Detailed Reference:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=asciicast