# Asset path notation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How do I include several Javascript and CSS files in my Ruby on Rails project?

Instead of having the files in `assets/javascript` and `assets/stylesheets`, the files are in directories of `/css` and `/js`. There is also a large number of subfolders within those directories.

I tried updating the `manifest.js` file and also tried including several of stylesheet links in the `application.html.erb`, but I the files are not being included in my project.

I would much rather point the manifest file at the folders I need so if I have files in all folders under `assets/css/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder`,  how would I do this?

I have the same question for Javascript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [require_tree](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) to include your parent `/js` and `/css` directories.

You could then do something like this

```
# application.js    
//= require_tree ./js

# application.css
*= require_tree ./css
```

Check out this comparable StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105387/require-tree-in-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was after.